# JavaScript export Attachment() classes from discord.js library

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am using the library browser way, I can not manage to attach the imgur png!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="discord.11.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    
// Create an instance of a Discord client
const client = new Discord.Client();
const atch = new Discord.MessageAttachment();

/**
 * The ready event is vital, it means that only _after_ this will your bot start reacting to information
 * received from Discord
 */
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
  // If the message is '!rip'
  if (message.content === '!rip') {
    // Create the attachment using MessageAttachment
    const attachment = new atch.MessageAttachment('https://i.imgur.com/w3duR07.png');
    // Send the attachment in the message channel
    message.channel.send(attachment);
  }
});
    
    
  client.login('BOT TOKEN HERE');
</script>
```

Thats all I have. Here is the doc link that I have got: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.6.4/examples/attachments

I can't adapt the code to get it running! OR this library isn't just completed for broswer?

The error im getting:

```
index.html:19 Uncaught TypeError: attachments is not a constructor
```

What exactly is not right here?

Comment: Why are you not using `Discord.MessageAttachment`?

Comment: Tried just now, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
    at new MessageAttachment (discord.11.6.4.min.js:1)
    at index.html:7` error.